# Determining Hyperfine Hamiltonian Term

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, hamiltonian, matrix-elements, hyperfine-structure

I'm having difficulty determining the hyperfine Hamiltonian term for a hydrogen-like atom ($^{87}$Rb & $^{85}$Rb). The hyperfine Hamiltonian is given by:

$${\hat{H}}_{hf}=a_{hf}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left({\hat{S}}_+{\hat{I}}_-+{\hat{S}}_-{\hat{I}}_+\right)+{\hat{S}}_z{\hat{I}}_z\right)$$

Where the matrix elements are given by:

$$\begin{align}
\langle m_s',m_I'|{\hat{S}}_+{\hat{I}}_-|m_s,m_I\rangle &= \hbar^2\sqrt{\left(S-m_s\right)\left(S+m_s+1\right)\left(I+m_I\right)\left(I-m_I+1\right)}\ \delta_{m_s+1,m_s'}\delta_{m_I-1,m_I'} \\
\langle m_s',m_I'|{\hat{S}}_-{\hat{I}}_+|m_s,m_I\rangle &= \hbar^2\sqrt{\left(S+m_s\right)\left(S-m_s+1\right)\left(I-m_I\right)\left(I+m_I+1\right)}\ \delta_{m_s-1,m_s'}\delta_{m_I+1,m_I'} \\
\langle m_s',m_I'|{\hat{S}}_z{\hat{I}}_z|m_s,m_I\rangle &= \hbar^2m_sm_I\ \delta_{m_s,m_s'}\delta_{m_I,m_I'}
\end{align}$$

For $^{87}$Rb, the nuclear spin is $I = \frac 32$ and the allowed values of the magnetic spin  are: $-\frac 32$, $-\frac 12$, $\frac 12$, $\frac 32$. The value of $S$ is simply $S = \frac 12$ and the allowed magnetic spin values are $-\frac 12$ and $\frac 12$. The size of the matrix should be $8\times 8$. I'm just not quite sure how to go about filling the terms of the Hamiltonian as it has been a number of years since I have done quantum.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/168783) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/168783) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the operator is represented by a $8\times 8$ matrix,
because you have $8$ different base states $|m_s,m_I\rangle$.
There is not a single correct way of ordering the $8$ base states.
You are free to choose any sequence for them.
So let's choose this sequence
(with the $m_s$ and $m_I$ sorted in descending order):

$$\begin{matrix}
|b_1\rangle=|+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{3}{2}\rangle \\
|b_2\rangle=|+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}\rangle \\
|b_3\rangle=|+\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle \\
|b_4\rangle=|+\frac{1}{2},-\frac{3}{2}\rangle \\
|b_5\rangle=|-\frac{1}{2},+\frac{3}{2}\rangle \\
|b_6\rangle=|-\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}\rangle \\
|b_7\rangle=|-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle \\
|b_8\rangle=|-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{3}{2}\rangle
\end{matrix}$$

But once you decided for a particular sequence,
you need to stick to it for filling the columns *and* the rows of every matrix.
So the $8\times 8$ matrix of any operator $\hat{A}$ is given by
$$\begin{align}
\hat{A}&=\begin{pmatrix}
\langle b_1|\hat{A}|b_1\rangle &
\langle b_1|\hat{A}|b_2\rangle &
\langle b_1|\hat{A}|b_3\rangle &
\cdots \\
\langle b_2|\hat{A}|b_1\rangle &
\langle b_2|\hat{A}|b_2\rangle &
\langle b_2|\hat{A}|b_3\rangle &
\cdots \\
\langle b_3|\hat{A}|b_1\rangle &
\langle b_3|\hat{A}|b_2\rangle &
\langle b_3|\hat{A}|b_3\rangle &
\cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{pmatrix} \\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
\langle+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{3}{2}|\hat{A}|+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{3}{2}\rangle &
\langle+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{3}{2}|\hat{A}|+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}\rangle &
\langle+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{3}{2}|\hat{A}|+\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle &
\cdots \\
\langle+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}|\hat{A}|+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{3}{2}\rangle &
\langle+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}|\hat{A}|+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}\rangle &
\langle+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}|\hat{A}|+\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle &
\cdots \\
\langle+\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}|\hat{A}|+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{3}{2}\rangle &
\langle+\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}|\hat{A}|+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}\rangle &
\langle+\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}|\hat{A}|+\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle &
\cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$

Notice how the $\langle\cdots|$ vary from row to row,
and the $|\cdots\rangle$ vary from column to column.

Now you can write down the matrices
$\hat{S}_+\hat{I}_-$, $\hat{S}_-\hat{I}_+$ and $\hat{S}_z\hat{I}_z$
using the formulas for the matrix elements given in your question.
The easiest one to write down is the matrix for $\hat{S}_z\hat{I}_z$:
$$\hat{S}_z\hat{I}_z=\hbar^2\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{2} & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2} & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}$$

Writing down the matrices for $\frac{1}{2}\hat{S}_+\hat{I}_-$
and $\frac{1}{2}\hat{S}_-\hat{I}_+$ needs more time and concentration.
Finally you can add these $3$ matrices to get the matrix of the hyperfine
Hamiltonian $\hat{H}_\text{hf}$.

Comment: Ok awesome! I was having difficult time trying to remember the formalisms of Dirac notation but now it seems to make sense. Really appreciate your help!